# Extract values from point layer to grid

Tags: qgis, raster

[image]

Usig QGIS. What i wan't to do is to calculate the mean value of the point layers attríbutes in an area of 100x100m. I created a grid with a size of 100x100 m but i need a method for extracting and calculate the values from the Point-layers and get them into the grid.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use Postigs? or you need a solution using only qgis?

Comment: You could try using the **Join attributes by location** tool from the _Processing Toolbox_ and in the `Statistics for summary` option, use `mean`.